# How to post a blog in google blog from my ASP.net App

Tags: asp.net

I wish to post a blog into my google blog page from my ASP.net app.  Is that possible?  Same concept in posting a link in facebook wall.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Refer to [Blogger API](https://developers.google.com/blogger/) documentation